# Modify a form control

Tags: excel, vba

I am wanting to create a macro in Excel 2013 that will modify the linked cell of a check box.

For example, say I have a lot of check boxes in column D that I want to link to D1, D2, D3, all the way to D999999 or whatever.  I can use a loop to do the repetitive part, but I don't know how I can tell it to change the linked value.

Comment: What type of checkbox, ActiveX or Forms?

Comment: Forms type checkbox

Answer (score 0):

For a form control checkbox, the syntax is to change a linked cell is:

```
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Check Box 1")).LinkedCell = "$J$1"
```

Comment: it gave me an error with that code, but I was able to modify it with the other suggestion and get a solution.  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to tie each checkbox to its underlying cell:

```
Sub LinkBoxes()
    Dim oCbx As CheckBox
    For Each oCbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        oCbx.LinkedCell = oCbx.TopLeftCell.Address
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is more what I'm looking for, its typing it to the cell to the up and left - the "TopLeftCell" obviously: if the box is in B2, it links it to A1.  While I can probably work with this, I'd think there's probably a way to connect B2 to B2, and so on.

Comment: I got it to work with this:


Sub LinkBoxes()
    Dim oCbx As CheckBox
    Dim selfCbx As String
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 2
    For Each oCbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    oCbx.LinkedCell = "$D$" & row
    row = row + 1
    Next
End Sub

thanks for your help.